# rails Display only the first 50 characters field in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view, field

Display only the first 50 characters <%= news.header %>
view:

```
<% @news.each do |news| %>
          <div class="news">
      <div class="title"> <%= news.title %> </div>
    <div class="photo"><%= image_tag( "1.jpg", :width =>247, :crop => :fit) %> </div>
      <div class="header"> <%= news.header %></div>
          <div class="cl"></div>
             </div>
    <% end %>
```

controller:

```
def index
@news=News.all
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<%= news.header.truncate(50) %>
```

See http://api.rubyonrails.org/v4.2.7/classes/String.html#method-i-truncate

Comment: Also you may add a `title` attribute on the `div` with the full header if required.

Comment: You can use the method in answer or this [method](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/TextHelper.html#method-i-truncate) also. matter of choice btw :)

Comment: @philip_hallstrom Thank you!